# Can the spectra of helium atom be solved by Schrodinger equation?

Tags: atomic-physics, schroedinger-equation, orbitals

Can the Schrodinger equation work out the spectra of helium atom, not all, but part of them?

Answer (score 2):

The Schrodinger equation is a non-relativistic approximation. It can describe the spectrum of any atom, including helium, to a good approximation but not precisely because it cannot describe relativistic effects. These relativistic effects are known as the [fine structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_structure).

In fact the fine structure of the helium spectrum is of interest because it provides a convenient way to measure a physical property important to relativistic quantum mechanics called the [fine structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant).

There is no analytic solution of the Schrodinger equation for a helium atom but the equation can be solved numerically to great accuracy. Typically we would do a [Hartree-Fock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree%E2%80%93Fock_method) calculation followed by [configuration interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_interaction).

Comment: Bethe and Salpeter wrote a very nice book on one- and two-electron atoms. Still good reading.